# Help drawing a timeline like this

Tags: timeline

Hi I am a beginner to LaTex. I would like to know how to draw a timeline like this please.

Many thanks.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to draw a timeline like this?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598883/how-to-draw-a-timeline-like-this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->] (0,0) to  (10,0);
  \foreach \x/\q/\w in {1/Text1,4/Text2,6/Text3,9/Text4}{
    \draw[line width=1pt, red] (\x,-2mm) node[below, black](\x){\q} -- (\x,2mm);
}
    \draw[dashed, blue, semithick]   (5,2)  node[left, xshift=-2.5cm]{Period1} node[right, xshift=2.5cm]{Period2}  --(5,-2);


\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Time Line Diagram} \label{fig:M1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

EDIT in response to OP question

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->] (0,0) to  (10,0);
  \foreach \x/\q/\w in {1/Text1,4/Text2,6/Text3,9/Text4}{
    \draw[line width=1pt, red] (\x,-2mm) node[below, black](\x){\q} -- (\x,2mm);
}
    \draw[dashed, blue, semithick]   (5,2)  node[left, xshift=-2.5cm, yshift=-1cm]{Period1} node[right, xshift=2.5cm]{Period2}  --(5,-2);


\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Time Line Diagram} \label{fig:M1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I shall thank you for your patience. Exactly the solution. As a final question, may I ask you how to put "period 1" and "period 2" further down? Thank you again.

Comment: I have done it for one side -- can you repeat it for the other side-- have a look at the edit above

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I have used "text 1" only for simplicity. Actually, I have large texts to include and with curly brackets I cannot use \\ to start a new line. Could you help me?